# Django Python change user default attributes for authentication

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models

In Django, the default attributes for user:
username
password
email
first_name
last_name

I would like to remove email, first_name, last_name 
and replace it with company

Is that possible ? Can someone show me the process of performing an authentication session with these 3 modified attributes:
- company
- username
- password

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation regarding [customizing authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/) in Django especially the part regarding [User model substitution](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) if you would like to create your own model.

Comment: thanks, can a username be not unique ? the username is only unique per company.

Comment: it can be whatever suits you if you do custom auth and model